# Wordpress with different site url causes homepage redirect loop when using postname permalinks

Tags: wordpress, fly

I am attempting to setup WordPress to work with fly.io, which requires the WordPress address and Site address to differ. I have `wp.example.com` pointing to my wp server and `example.com` pointing to fly. Which results in:

```
WordPress Address (URL): http://wp.example.com
Site Address (URL): http://example.com
```

This works until I set a static homepage while using the Post name permalink. Accessing the website results in a redirect loop. If I use the default Plain permalink, have the site and wp address match, or both, it's happy. This is only affecting the homepage.

Haven't touched .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```